# How to insert text into a string at a point of a specific character(s)

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have searched the whole internet, and the only things I can find is IndexOf. The issue with that is I need a way to put the insert at a specific one of those chars.

I am currently using this

```
    RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text.Insert(RichTextBox1.Text.Substring(0,RichTextBox1.Text.Split("^")(CurrentSlide).Length), "^")
```

Which of course is completely incorrect after thinking about it, because the length of the index is not the real length of the text to the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have the right idea. It seems like you have a "^" delimited string, and you want to insert an empty at some point. Since a collection is easier to work with than a string, your `Split` is a good start.

```
Dim parts = RichTextBox1.Text.Split("^")
```

Let's make that a list, so we can insert into it:

```
Dim parts = RichTextBox1.Text.Split("^").ToList()
```

Now, just insert an empty string where you want the new element:

```
Dim parts = RichTextBox1.Text.Split("^").ToList()
parts.Insert(CurrentSlide, "")
```

And combine them back for editing in your textbox:

```
Dim parts = RichTextBox1.Text.Split("^").ToList()
parts.Insert(CurrentSlide, "")
RichTextBox1.Text = String.Join("^", parts)
```

Comment: This answer is the solution, but can you explain how I would go about setting what text should be implemented after the "^" at the specific index (CurrentSlide)? I think I know what it is, but I want to be sure.

Comment: @SkorrloreGaming-Productions - in parts.Insert, you'd just put the text you wanted instead of empty string - eg., parts.Insert(CurrentSlide, "NewTextHere").